# How to obtain the chi squared value as an output of scipy.optimize.curve_fit?

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting, chi-squared

Is it possible to obtain the value of the chi squared as a direct output of `scipy.optimize.curve_fit()`?

Usually, it is easy to compute it after the fit by squaring the difference between the model and the data, weighting by the uncertainties and summing all up. However, it is not as direct when the parameter `sigma` is passed a 2D matrix (the covariance matrix of the data) instead of a simple 1D array.

Are really the best-fit parameters and its covariance matrix the only two outputs that can be extracted from `curve_fit()`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is not possible to obtain the value of chi^2 from `scipy.optimize.curve_fit` directly without manual calculations. It is possible to get additional output from `curve_fit` besides `popt` and `pcov` by providing the argument `full_output=True`, but the additional output does not contain the value of chi^2. (The additional output is documented e.g. at `leastsq` [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.leastsq.html#scipy.optimize.leastsq)).

In the case where `sigma` is a MxM array, the definition of the chi^2 function minimized by curve_fit is slightly different.
In this case, `curve_fit` minimizes the function `r.T @ inv(sigma) @ r`, where `r = ydata - f(xdata, *popt)`, instead of `chisq = sum((r / sigma) ** 2)` in the case of one dimensional `sigma`, see the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html) of the parameter `sigma`.
So you should also be able to calculate chi^2 in your case by using `r.T @ inv(sigma) @ r` with your optimized parameters.

An alternative would be to use another package, for example [lmfit](https://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/), where the value of chi square can be directly obtained from the fit result:

```
from lmfit.models import GaussianModel

model = GaussianModel()

# create parameters with initial guesses:
params = model.make_params(center=9, amplitude=40, sigma=1)  

result = model.fit(n, params, x=centers)
print(result.chisqr)
```

Comment: `lmfit` is indeed a great package. Unfortunately, it does not offer the option to pass an MxM matrix to `sigma` but only a 1D array. Hope this can be implemented in the future.